# How can I send the RESTAPI call to all 3 of the GET()/POST() by using the single button click of Submit() button in my WebClient side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have a **Single Web Page that contains multiple Tab**. I don't want user to click save in each tab. I want them to finish edit the data and click Submit only once at the end of their transaction.
My doubt is that for each tab(Order/Customer/Vendor) tabs has their own set of controller(OrdersController, CustomerController & VendorController) and own GET()/POST() methods accordingly in the WebAPI backend.

(From Web Client side)

- How can I send the RESTAPI call to all 3 of the GET()/POST() by using the single button click of Submit() button in my WebClient side?
- How should I handle back the replyRequest from WebAPI? Should I send multiple call in 1 single Submit button and it will return multiple reply message to web client?
- (From Web API side)

  - What is the best practice to design the WebAPI controller GET()/POST()?

    - Should I write 3 of the GET()/POST() method in 1 single controller?
    - Should I continue current design(separate each GET()/POST() method according to DataModel)

Comment: Even if it's technically possible to fire 3 restcalls(just execute the three calls in a row, asynchronous, whatever) on the submit click, you don't need to trigger the event, but to execute they're business logic. But from my point of view too much is happening, too much is happening the invisible way...think of a better design... But at first plz clarify why you want to do it that way, –

Answer (score 0):

To make the life easier you may combine all three methods in three different controllers in one super method and send all the data to that method.
If it is not possible to combine all methods into one, at least all methods should be in one controller and One method may call other methods on the server. 
In my opinion there should be one call only from client to server.

> What is the best practice to design the WebAPI controller GET()/POST()?

Using common sense!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make 1 single call that will do everything, and separate the business logic from the API using services:

```
public IActionResult Save(OrderInput input)
{
    _orderService.CreateOrder(new Order{ ... });

    _customerService.UpdateBalance(input.CustomerId, input.TotalAmount);

    // return whatever you want here...

}
```